# How to connect Oracle database 19c to IIS?

Tags: php, windows, oracle, iis

I've installed IIS and PHP and now I want to connect Oracle database (version 19c). I want to manage data with PHP but I dont now how to start. Everything must working on local server. And there's a question - Can I do it on Windows 10 or need I to install Windows Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ["Database Installation Guide for Microsoft Windows" for Oracle Database Release 19 Section "Oracle Database Software Requirements"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ntdbi/oracle-database-software-requirements.html#GUID-CEF225E9-9600-4E01-AC6F-402B562385F8):

> Oracle Database for Windows x64 is supported on the following operating systems:
>
> ...
>
> - Windows 10 x64 - Pro, Enterprise, and Education editions
>
> ...

So yes, Windows 10 should do it, unless it's a Home edition.